# How to fetch JsonNode values using string variable as key?

Tags: java, json, jsonnode

I am trying to fetch values from a `JsonNode` in order to carry out some validations.
However, I get null when i try to fetch the value using a predefined variable (String).
When I fetch the same value using hardcoded key, it gives me the correct value.

I tried naming a new variable String as the key, but it does not seem to be working as expected.

```java
boolean validateFormData(JsonNode formData) {
    System.out.println("1-" + formData.get("name"));
    
    String nameVar = "name";

    System.out.println("2-" + formData.get(nameVar));
    
    return false;
}
```

> 1-"Mohammed"
>
> 2-null

Is being printed I am not sure why.
The reason I want to use a variable is because the keys are not fixed, they vary from Form to Form.
I am new to stackoverflow so kindly ignore the formatting errors.
I shall get better with time.
Any help is appreciated, thanks in advance.
Even if the question is repeated kindly point me to the right answer.

Comment: JsonNode class is from which library ?

Comment: Can you try calling the variable-based get method first and telling us the results? If it returns a value but the normal one fails, then this could be a bug. Otherwise, you could always try [JsonNode.findValue(String fieldName)](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.2.0/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/JsonNode.html#findValue(java.lang.String))

Comment: @TechFree, `JsonNode` is from `com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode` library. 
I figured out a way to handle the get request.
`formData.get(nameVar)` returns `JsonNode`. 
Its SysOut returns `"Mohammed"` with double quotes. 
I tried `formData.get(nameVar).textValue()` and it returns `Mohammed` without double quotes.

Comment: @Mohammed Which version of jackson-databind.jar are you using ? This works for me, do you have some other code in between which probably is changing the nameVar ? Can you also print formData and see if that is fine ? Add the formData in your question.

Comment: @TechFree I am using 2.9.8 version of jackson-databind. 
The problem was nameVar was not a string, it was being fetched from another `JsonNode`. Hence it was returning with double quotes. I used textValue and it works fine.
Thanks for your time.